# Placing image over check-box without using css

Tags: angularjs

How to change image over check-box during on-click and off-clickin angularjs if on-click and off-click image is coming from server. Here is my javascript code where I'm making request to server.

```
var url = "http://"+window.localStorage.getItem("ip")+"/api/v1/pins/details/"+userID; 
console.log(url);
$http.get(url)
.success(function(data){
  console.log("groups",data);
  $scope.result = data;
});
```

and my html code is:

```
<ul class="list">
    <li class="item item" ng-repeat="a in result.result | filter: a.groupName=sortby">
            <!--{{a.alias}}-->
        <label for="a.switchID">    
          <img style="height:32px;width: 32px;position: absolute;left:6px;top:13px;" class="image" src="http://png.findicons.com/files/icons/1588/farm_fresh_web/32/lightbulb_off.png"/> //this image i have taken from example.
        </label>  
          <input id="a.switchID" type="checkbox" ng-change="send(a.deviceID,a.pinNumber)" ng-model="value4 ">
          </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

so I"m fetching JSON data from server which has on and off image URL. So how can I change it on click.

Comment: Post HTML and JS code.

Comment: Html Code:<ul class="list">
        <li class="item item" ng-repeat="a in result.result | filter: a.groupName=sortby">
             
              <input id="a.switchID" type="checkbox" ng-change="send(a.deviceID,a.pinNumber)" ng-model="value4 ">
              </div>
        </li>
      </ul>

Comment: And in Javascript I'm calling data from server.

Comment: With this html code I'm able to place image over check box:                    <li class="item item" ng-repeat="a in result.result | filter: a.groupName=sortby">
                <!--{{a.alias}}-->
            <label for="a.switchID">    
              <img style="height:32px;width: 32px;position: absolute;left:6px;top:13px;" class="image" src="http://png.findicons.com/files/icons/1588/farm_fresh_web/32/lightbulb_off.png"/>
            </label>  
              <input id="a.switchID" type="checkbox" ng-change="send(a.deviceID,a.pinNumber)" ng-model="value4 ">
              </div>
        </li>

Comment: but here i want to change image on click which is in ng-repeat, i.e my data coming from server.

Comment: Can you update question with code?

Comment: I have updated my question.  @dfsq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For custom checkbox most implementations would still keep the checkbox intact, just hidden, and it will be activated by using label. So the `ng-model` in the checkbox would still work and data processing need not change.

The following demo is using the style from http://codepen.io/CreativeJuiz/pen/BiHzp
You can pretty much use any custom css as long as they still keep the checkbox.

```js
angular.module('test', [])

.controller('Test', function($scope){
  $scope.lightbulb = {
    id: 4,
    name: 'light',
    icon: {
      on: 'http://png.findicons.com/files/icons/1588/farm_fresh_web/32/lightbulb.png',
      off: 'http://png.findicons.com/files/icons/1588/farm_fresh_web/32/lightbulb_off.png'
    }
  }
  
  $scope.getIcon = function(data){
    if (data.icon) {
      if (data.isChecked) return data.icon.on;
      else return data.icon.off;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox] + label {
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='test' ng-controller='Test'>
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-attr-id="{{'c' + lightbulb.id}}" ng-model="lightbulb.isChecked" />
    <label ng-attr-for="{{'c' +lightbulb.id}}">
      <img ng-src="{{getIcon(lightbulb)}}">
      {{lightbulb.name}}
    </label>
  </p>
  
  <div>{{lightbulb.isChecked}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have changed my question, can u please review it?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

View:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="changeImage()" > 

<img src="{{imgSource}}"/>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.imgSource="img1.jpg";

$scope.changeImage = function() {
  $scope.imgSource = "img2.jpg";
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question please review it.  @Dawid Pawlowski